Why does the mean short rate in my QuantLib Hull-White model diverge from the forward curve over time?
I’m simulating short rates using QuantLib’s Hull-White model and plotting the continuously compounded 1-day SONIA rate. I compare the mean short rate from 10,000 simulated paths to the forward curve, but I notice significant divergence over time, especially when the mean reversion parameter is low. The model is calibrated using swaption data.
Is this divergence between the mean short rate and the forward curve expected?
